# Tomcat doesn't start after windows update

Tags: tomcat, startup, windows-update

I've an instance of `Apache Tomcat6` installed and it was running without any exceptions, until I ran windows update. As soon as the update was complete, I rebooted the system and found tomcat was not running. I tried to run manually, but of no use. Also, I tried to execute it with from `command prompt` using the commands

```
%Tomcat%bin> tomcat6.exe start
%Tomcat%bin> tomcat6 //TS// tomcat
```

It didn't start my tomcat. I tried to look into log files for any trace of errors, in the `catalina` logs I found

```
09-Jul-2015 13:16:46.101 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"
09-Jul-2015 13:16:46.194 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "tomcat"
09-Jul-2015 13:16:46.194 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "tomcat"
09-Jul-2015 13:16:46.241 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "tomcat"
09-Jul-2015 13:16:46.553 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "manager"
09-Jul-2015 15:15:54.615 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"
```

Thought it might be an issue with user-cred, so tried updating `tomcat-users` roles and users. It didn't work.

Is there any issue with `windows update`, as before the update tomcat was working fine. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: run the tomcat/jre as root, check permission and firewall

Comment: What do you mean by run jre as root??

Comment: Login as root(administrator) and try it, root=administrator

Comment: Yup, I'm running as root and disabled the firewall (for the timebeing)

Comment: do other java apps work probably? try to start tomcat via `{CATALINA}/bin/startup.bat`

Comment: No other errors in any of TomCat's other logs? Could I get you to doublecheck that?

Comment: I've checked other log files, none of them looks like an error @TDHofstetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your context, I guess when you run windows update it might have updated the java version. Eventually, your jre gets updated and possibly your `jvm.dll` path might be pointing to older version of java, where it doesn't actually exist.

Try updating the `jvm.dll` path in `tomcat config -> java options`.

If that doesn't work re-installation might be your plan B. Hope that might work.